# ErrorException Property [ruta_foto] does not exist on this collection instance. Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buen día,

Tengo la siguiente función en un controlador de laravel

public function Show($id){

```
    $configuracion = FrontConfiguracion::find(1);

    $contacto = FrontDatosContacto::find(1);

    $areas = FrontAreas::find($id);

    $funcionarios = FrontTalentoHumano::all()->where('area_id','=',$id);

    return view('front.acerca-entidad.listar-talento-humano', compact('configuracion', 'contacto', 'areas', 'funcionarios'));

}
```

El problema es que cuando voy a llamar la vista, me sale el siguiente error:
[image: Error laravel 5.4]

Pude notar que me reconoce los modelos de configuracion, contacto y areas; pero en funcionarios solo muestra **Collection** en lugar de reconocer el modelo **FrontTalentoHumano** que es el que le corresponde en este caso...

Así es como hago la llamada a la propiedad dentro de listar-talento-humano.blade.php  [image: Llamada a la propiedad desde la vista]

Espero que puedan ayudarme y darme una luz, puesto que llevo varios días con este error y el proyecto atrasado.

¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Puedes poner el codigo de la plantilla listar-talento-humano.blade.php?  da la sensación de que quieres acceder a la propiedad ruta_foto dentro del collection, en lugar de uno de los elementos (algo como funcionarios->ruta_foto en lugar de **funcionarios[item]->ruta_foto**)

Comment: Precisamente eso es lo que intento hacer, lo que no entiendo es cómo funciona eso de llamar a **funcionarios[item]->ruta_foto**

Comment: por favor, pon el codigo de la plantilla en texto plano, no en imagen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en tu codigo, funcionarios es una collection debido al

```
$funcionarios = FrontTalentoHumano::all()->where('area_id','=',$id);
```

ya que supongo que habra varios funcionarios en ese area, verdad?

lo que tienes que hacer en la plantilla es un bucle, por ej, con foreach:

```
@foreach ($funcionarios as $funcionario)
    <img src="../{{funcionario->ruta_foto}}">
@endforeach
```

De esta manera, en cada $funcionario tienes uno de los elementos. Esto te imprimirá varias imagenes seguidas. Deberas adaptarlo a tu necesidad en concreto.

Echale un vistazo a la documentación del motor de plantillas blade, en https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade.

Personalmente me gusta mas twig (porque uso symfony) pero en algunos casos es bastante parecido.